# Pluralization with number and name (swift stringsdict)

Tags: ios, swift, pluralize

I have a stringdict and following sentence I want to translate in several languages:

```
<key>myKey</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>My friend %#@name@ has %#@count@.</string>
    <key>count</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>one dog</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%d dogs</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

What I want is to use following code, to create my String

```
let name = "Peter"
let dogs = 3
let myString = String(format: NSLocalizedString("myKey", comment:""), name, dogs)
```

I have expected to get "My friend Peter has 3 dogs.", but I get an error. So maybe have someone a tip and can help me, how I could use strings in the dict, or maybe there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to what [Andreas said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49811610/1187415): There is no dictionary for the
`%#@name@` variable in the format string, but you can simply use `%@`
for a Swift string instead. The complete stringsdict entry then
becomes

```
<key>myKey</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
    <string>My friend %@ has %#@count@.</string>
    <key>count</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
        <string>d</string>
        <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
        <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
        <key>one</key>
        <string>one dog</string>
        <key>other</key>
        <string>%d dogs</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: How would you translate the ```My friend %@ has``` part?

Comment: @gpichler: I am not sure if I understand your question. You have one stringsdict file for every supported language. The German version would contain the entry `<string>Mein Freund %@ hat %#@count@.</string>`

Comment: Hmm I think it's an issue with our translation tool then. It doesn't show the ```NSStringLocalizedFormatKey``` as translatable but only the ```<string>``` elements in the second dict.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the format type key:

```
<key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
<string>d</string>
```

For more details on this, see [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)

Comment: the "dogs" are not the problem, this is working. The problem is, that I don't know how to handle the name, because this shouldnt be changed in the stringsdict.